# Using SetTimeout and .each Jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to use settimeout() function with .each function.Basically iwant to show each image for 5 seconds and then next but i am only able to see last image.The .each executes and do not stop for 3 seconds.How can i do this?This is how i am doing.

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#Images').find('li').each(function () {
            var img = this;
            setTimeout(function () {
                Start(img);
            }, 3000);

        });


    });
    function Start(img) {
        $('#slideshow').html(img);
    }
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="slideshow">
</div>
<div style="display:none;">
<ul id="Images">
<li><img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" /></li>
<li><img src="images/Ajax Loader White.gif" /></li>
<li><img src="images/fancybox_sprite.png" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: have you tried the .delay() function?  I'm thinking this will do what you need.  The way you're doing it, each call to Start() will be within milliseconds of each other.

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
    $('#Images').find('li').each(function (k,v) {
        var img = this;
        changeImg(img, k);
    });

    function changeImg(img, k) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            Start(img);
        }, 3000*(k+1));
    }
```

Comment: Can you please explain what does this mean .each(function(k,v)

Comment: k is the index from 0 to n-1, v is the value element (v is unneeded in this case)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var images = $('#Images').find('li');
var imageCount = images.length;
var counter = 0;
setTimeout(function(){
Start(images[counter++]);
if(counter>=imageCount)
    counter =0 ;

},3000);
```